# What are the colours of the Magical Girl's Rings?

Tags: madoka-magica

I always thought the colour of the ring matched the Soul Gem. However after deciphering the runs on the ring I got with a Mami Soul Gem Necklace which said HOMURA, I looked up on the wiki and saw that Mami's is actually purple not yellow like her soul gem.

So I am wondering what are the colors of the rings for each of the magical girls?

EXTRA: I actually brought 6 Ring/Soul Gem Necklace with the 6th set having Homura's Soul Gem and a Green Ring.

EDIT: my mistake, it's a Green Soul Gem and Pink Ring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the list at [the Madoka wiki](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Merchandise:Accessories_and_Apparel#Soul_Gem_Rings):

- [Madoka Kaname](http://www.cospa.com/detail/id/00000039996) (pink) - [image]
- [Homura Akemi](http://www.cospa.com/detail/id/00000039991) (purple) - [image]
- [Mami Tomoe](http://www.cospa.com/detail/id/00000039984) (yellow) - [image]
- [Sayaka Miki](http://www.cospa.com/detail/id/00000039979) (blue) - [image]
- [Kyoko Sakura](http://www.cospa.com/detail/id/00000039971) (magenta) - [image]

You can see in each of the images the name on the back corresponds with the name in the image (which I translated from [this online translator](http://p.mcfog.com/madoka-runes/)). So it seems the colors *are* the same as the color of their [soul gems](http://www.amiami.com/top/detail/detail?gcode=CGD2-12302). It seems the [green soul gem](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Puella-Madoka-Magica-Necklace-Cosplay/dp/B00CYLF0NA/ref=pd_sim_sbs_k_h_b_cs_5/279-2095054-0973726) also belonged to Madoka Kaname.

The list can also be seen in this [Crunchyroll news post](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2012/09/12-1/madoka-magica-sells-its-soul-gems-this-november).

Comment: that last link of the Green Soul Gem, that's the same one i brought, the other 5 are just like that, looking at all the rings Mami's name is on the blue one so i'm guessing they may be incorrect replicas and you can only pick Homura's and Madoka's set by the colour since they have the same image on the box, the Boxes for Mami, Sayaka and Kyoko all have their image on them, i'm unsure of the Green Soul Gem as it has the same image on the box as Madoka's and Homura's however the pink ring might mean it's Madoka's but from another timeline